# How to setup remote desktop connection for all users?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

We are having some remote desktop connections for all users. Our .rdp files are configured and copied to all workstations, but on each workstation, when different user logs in and run that .rdp file, it always requires to enter password at the first time to use it. Is there a way that .rdp file can store the passoword for all users?

where is the configuration files located for .rdp files? there must be file that holding all .rdp file settings right?

Comment: The credentials are stored in the Windows Credential Manager, not in the RDP shortcut.

Comment: I took a look of Windows Credential Manager, just wondering that if it supports %COMPUTERNAME% variable?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 @scott chamberlain @PrinceYann      I just made it working. create a batch file, put it into startup folder. `cmdkey /add:TERMSRV/server01 /user:%computername% /pass:password` . we are using pc name as terminal server login name, so i user %computername% here. now no matter who logs into workstations, they all get same credentials for rdp. thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the password pre saved in the rdp file and have it distributable. The rdp file format does support saving passwords as a undocumented feature (so it could be removed in a future version), however the password is encrypted with the "machine key" of the windows install so only the machine that encrypted the password is capable of decrypting it.

Answer (score 0):

To configure the credentials in each PC, go to the control panel on the PC that has the credentials working for all users, then procede to user accounts, credential manager, windows credentials and make a backup of the credentials. After that, import that backup in each other PC.

The names may differ, I'm using the portuguese version.

Comment: The thing is we dont control who is working on which PC, so there is no PC has the credentials working for all users. The thing i want to setup is like a default setting, no matter who is login to PC, they all will using the same credentails for that .rdp connection.

Comment: just wondering that if credential manager supports %COMPUTERNAME% variable?